# Android: Changing color of window background when using FLAG_SECURE

Tags: android

I have a request that when the my Android application is placed into the background that I blank out the screen to hide sensitive data.  This was easy enough to implement using the:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

The difficult part appears to be changing the color of that blank screen you get when looking at the apps in the background.  By default it appears to be white and I can't seem to find a way to override that.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: is this the only solution right now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't customize the color of the thumbnail in the recents view.

As you can see in [TaskViewThumbnail](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/views/TaskViewThumbnail.java#L150) the default color of the thumbnail (`0xffffffff`) is hardcoded, so it's not customizable:

```
/** Updates the paint to draw the thumbnail. */
void updateThumbnailPaintFilter() {
    if (mInvisible) {
        return;
    }
    int mul = (int) ((1.0f - mDimAlpha) * mThumbnailAlpha * 255);
    int add = (int) ((1.0f - mDimAlpha) * (1 - mThumbnailAlpha) * 255);
    if (mBitmapShader != null) {
        mLightingColorFilter.setColorMultiply(Color.argb(255, mul, mul, mul));
        mLightingColorFilter.setColorAdd(Color.argb(0, add, add, add));
        mDrawPaint.setColorFilter(mLightingColorFilter);
        mDrawPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    } else {
        int grey = mul + add;
        mDrawPaint.setColorFilter(null);
        mDrawPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255, grey, grey, grey));
    }
    invalidate();
}
```