# How to change background when onClick recent apps Android Studio

Tags: android

I have a problem when I code project by Android Studio which is like that:
When we use us apps, if we click into Recent apps button, our apps will be minimize and we can see almost information of Apps. And now, I would like when click into Recent Apps button, we can not see any information and it will become into a picture, or background color. and maximize it become normal.
Can anyone give me a suggestion some keyword or guide.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your onCreate

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Thank you, It's so good, but, now I would like to create new View to change, there is a white background like that instead.

Comment: It's not possible. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249526/android-changing-color-of-window-background-when-using-flag-secure

Comment: Thank you, can we change into any images ?